# Do I need temp file when ftp retrieving files?

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am using `ftpClient.retrieveFile()` to download files from an FTP Server while another thread is scanning the directory constantly for files to process. I am wondering if this is dangerous? Could it be that a file is not finished downloading and is processed by the other thread? Should I be using a `.temp` suffix to save the temporary file and rename it after the transaction is finished?

Answer (score 0):

Files are, in general, visible to other processes or threads as soon as you create them. So your second thread could see and process a file before you have completed writing to it. The correct practice is to use either a temporary extension (like the .temp you have mentioned) or a temporary directory.

In your case, the most appropriate thing to do would be to use some synchronization mechanism so that the second thread blocks when there are no files to process and the first thread notifies the second when a file finishes downloading. Java supports these operations with the `wait()` and `notify()` methods of the `Object` class.

Comment: thank you, after file transfer completed I should use file.saveto() to rename the file? is that the saveto method consume no IO and could be considered atomic operation?

Comment: @J-E-Double-F You can use `renameTo()` of the `File` class to rename files. It may or may not be atomic depending on the platform. What library are you using to manipulate files? I can't find any that has a `file.saveto()` method.

Comment: OMG I'm so sorry for the mistake, renameTo() is the exact method I use. My bad.